# 3 level nested dictionary comprehension in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, nested-loops, dictionary-comprehension

I have a Python dictionary as follows:

```
d = {'1': {'1': 3, '2': 1, '3': 1, '4': 4, '5': 2, '6': 3},
     '2': {'1': 3, '2': 3, '3': 1, '4': 2},
     '3': {'1': 1, '2': 1, '3': 3, '4': 2, '5': 1, '6': 1, '7': 1},
     '4': {'1': 1, '2': 1, '3': 3, '4': 2, '5': 1, '6': 1, '7': 1}}
```

I have this operation on the dictionary:

```
D = {}
for ko, vo in d.items():
  for ki, vi in vo.items():
    for i in range(vi):
      D[f'{ko}_{ki}_{i}'] = someFunc(ko, ki, i)
```

I want to translate it into a one liner with dictionary comprehension as follows:

```
D = {f'{ko}_{ki}_{i}': someFunc(ko, ki, i) for i in range(vi) for ki, vi in vo.items() for ko, vo in d.items()}
```

But I get an error

> NameError: name 'vi' is not defined

Can someone help me with the correct syntax for achieving this?

Comment: The order of loops should be the same as in your nested loops, not reversed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order of the loops has to be reversed.

This is what you're looking for:

```py
D = {f'{ko}_{ki}_{i}': someFunc(ko, ki, i) for ko, vo in d.items() for ki, vi in vo.items() for i in range(vi)  }
```

Answer (score 1):

The `for` clauses in the list comprehension should appear in the **same** order as in the equivalent for-loop code. The only thing that "moves" is that the innermost assignment is replaced by an expression at the beginning.

Please see https://treyhunner.com/2015/12/python-list-comprehensions-now-in-color/ for details.